# How to change and re-pickle a value in python

Tags: python, pickle

I am trying to add a function to my program that keeps usernames and high scores from all of the times it was ran. The function should load the high scores from the previous times the game was played and be able to append a user/score tuple to the list scores. The code below, to my understanding, should work, but for some reason it will only show the user/score set from the current time that the program was ran. How can I edit this code to accomplish this. Sorry for being this new, I am just trying to understand...

```
import pickle

    score = 12

    def scor_func(score):
      scores = []
      name = input("Please enter your name: ")
      entry = (name, score)
      scores.append(entry)
      f = open("Triviascores.bat", "wb")
      pickle.dump(scores, f)

      f.close()

      f = open("Triviascores.bat", "rb")
      scores = pickle.load(f)
      f.close()
      return scores

    scores = scor_func(score)
    print(scores)
```

Comment: unpickle (load). make changes. pickle (dump). order matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You swapped your operations here.

Your code creates an empty `scores` list, adds one entry, then saves that list. After that you load the file again, so you load *just* the new list you just created.

You need to first *load* the previous scores, append the new scores, *then* save the data:

```
def scor_func(score):
    name = input("Please enter your name: ")
    entry = (name, score)

    scorefile = "Triviascores.bat"
    if os.path.exists(scorefile):
        with open(scorefile, 'rb') as sf:
            scores = pickle.load(sf)
    else:
        scores = []

    scores.append(entry)

    with open(scoresfile, "wb") as sf:
        pickle.dump(scores, sf)

    return scores
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I finally got it sorted out. I am new to the concept of "pickling". Still trying to get the hang of how it works.